# Domain name of main website to be linked with blog hosted elsewhere

Tags: subdomain

For a website (Linux hosting with GoDaddy) with a domain name (www.mywebsite.com), it is intended to be linked with a blogspot blog (at present www.mywebsite.blogspot.com) which should be going forward blog.mywebsite.com. Is it possible buying subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Here are GoDaddy's docs on adding a subdomain to your GoDaddy hosted website.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-subdomain-19991